# Cannot Update Java plugin for Google Chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome

I keep getting the "Java plugin out of date" box whenever I open a page with embedded Java. I use the link provided, which has no auto-install. I've unzipped the tarball into `/usr/lib/jvm/`. I've used `chrome://plugins` to check the current version, extracted the path from the details to verify the correct file, and manually edited `.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences` to update the information for Java.

When I reopen chrome, it overwrites that Preferences file, thereby losing all the changes. I cannot find any documentation on how to update this. It's becoming rather frustrating, and is preventing me from using some software required by my school so I can view assignments, etc.

The current path of the plugin: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so`

The desired path of the plugin: `/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0_04/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chrome will look for the plugin in Firefox's plugin directory, so make a symbolic link from your java installation to there:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0_04/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so ~/.mozilla/plugins
```

Then restart Chrome, check chrome://plugins again and disable the old plugin.

Comment: I deleted my previous comments, as even though the folder didn't exist, by creating it and then doing the symlink, it worked. Thanks!